# Sketching a phase portrait and proving it has no periodic orbits

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, dynamical-systems

I'm doing this exercise:

> Consider the following differential equation system:
>
> $$\begin{cases}\dot{x}=x(1-x-ay) \\\dot{y}=y(1-y-bx)\end{cases}$$
>
> With $a,b>0$ and different to $1$. Sketch the phase portrait on the first quadrant and prove it has no periodic orbits.

What I've done so far is to find the equilibrium points. We make

$$\begin{cases}0=x(1-x-ay) \\0=y(1-y-bx)\end{cases}$$

and we find equilibrium points at $(0,0), (1,0), (0,1)$ and at the intersection point between $x=1-ay\ $ and $y=1-bx$, wich is

$$x=\frac{1-a}{1-ab},\  y=\frac{1-b}{1-ab}.$$

Once we have this, we have to check what's the local behaviour og the orbits near every equilibrium point:

We first find $$J=\begin{pmatrix}
-x+(-1+x+ay) & -xa\\ 
 -yb & -y+(-1+y+bx)
\end{pmatrix},$$

but checking every equilibrium point $(J_{(0,0)},J_{(1,0)},J_{(0,1)},\dots )$ doesn't give me nothing.

Am I missing something? Once I have the local behavior on the equilibrium points, how can I prove it has no periodic orbits?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: 1) Nullclines? 2) When you say checking the Jacobian gives nothing, have you classified each for all relevant parameter values? 3) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9%E2%80%93Bendixson_theorem

Comment: @erfink The OP asks how to prove that the system has **no** periodic orbits, so the reference on the Poincaré–Bendixson theorem is not relevant here.

Comment: @user539887 From Poincare Bendixson, index theory is a pretty immediate extension (particularly for dynamics in the plane). In particular, a periodic orbit in the plane must encircle one or more fixed points...cf. http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Poincare-Bendixson_theorem#Index_Theory

Comment: The OP found (at least for $a, b \in (0, 1)$) an equilibrium in the first quadrant.

Comment: @user539887 Yep, so any periodic orbit remaining strictly in the first quadrant must go around this point. But nullclines rule out such orbits. QED.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have any conditions on the values of $a,b$? Calculating the Jacobian I got, 
$$ J\left( x,y \right)=\left[ \begin{matrix}
   1-2x-ay & -ax  \\
   -by & 1-bx-2y  \\
\end{matrix} \right] $$
Then $ J\left( 0,0 \right)={{I}_{2\times 2}} $ so the origin is unstable. Let $\sigma(A)$ denote the set of eigenvalues of $A$. Then,

$$ \sigma \left( J\left( 0,1 \right) \right)=\left\{ -1,1-a \right\}\quad \text{and}\quad \sigma \left( J\left( 1,0 \right) \right)=\left\{ -1,1-b \right\} $$

so for $a,b >1$ these equilibria will be stable. Finally,

$$\sigma \left( J\left( \frac{a-1}{ab-1},\frac{b-1}{ab-1} \right) \right)=\left\{ \frac{(a-1)(b-1)}{ab-1},\frac{1-ab}{ab-1} \right\} $$

If $a>1, b>1$ then the first eigenvalue here is positive; so this one is unstable.

Here is a plot for $a=b=2$ with the equilibria marked in red.

[image: Phase plot]

Comment: Sorry, yes, edited.

Comment: Okay so for a complete answer you would also have to check what happens when $0<a,b<1$.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know how to prove it has no periodic orbits?

Comment: You would appeal to one of the theorems at: http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Periodic_orbit#Existence_.28or_Non-Existence.29_of_Periodic_Orbits

Comment: @Relure Particularly you should use following observations. No periodic orbit can intersect axes (because they are invariant -- just check nullclines). Since the problem asks you about the first quadrant, you can safely conclude that if there is a periodic orbit, it should be located in the interior of this quadrant. A periodic orbit encloses a bounded domain which necessarily contains at least one equilibrium point of index 1 or a bunch of equilibria with sum of indexes equal to 1. Here you go.

Comment: To prove the nonexistence of periodic orbits in the first quadrant you can also use the method ascribed to Nikolai Bautin: apply [Bendixson–Dulac theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bendixson%E2%80%93Dulac_theorem), with $\varphi(x,y) = 1/(xy)$ as a Dulac function.

Answer (score 1):

Calling

$$
x_0 = \frac{1-a}{a b - 1}\\
y_0 = \frac{1-b}{a b - 1}
$$

We have the behavior near $(x_0,y_0)$

$$
\dot X = J_0  X
$$

with

$$
X = (x-x_0,y-y_0)^{\top} \ \ \mbox{and}\ \ J_0 = \left(\begin{array}{cc}
\frac{1-a}{ab-1} & \frac{a(1-a)}{ab-1}\\
\frac{b(b-1)}{ab-1} & \frac{1-b}{ab-1}\end{array}\right)
$$

Analyzing the $J_0$ eigenvalues we obtain

$$
\{\frac{(a-1)(b-1)}{ab-1},-1\}
$$

then $(x_0,y_0)$ never can be a center.

Also there are no periodic limit cycles because applying the Bendixson-Dulac criteria with $\phi(x,y) = x^{\alpha}y^{\beta}$

we have

$$
(\phi(x,y)x(1-x-a y))_x+(\phi(x,y)y(1-y-bx))_y = -\phi(x,y)((2+a+a\alpha+\beta)x+(2+\alpha+b+b\beta)y)-(2+\alpha+\beta))
$$

Now making

$$
\alpha = \frac{2-a(b+1)}{ab-1}
$$

and

$$
\beta = \frac{2-b(a+1)}{ab-1}
$$

we have

$$
(\phi(x,y)x(1-x-a y))_x+(\phi(x,y)y(1-y-bx))_y = \phi(x,y)\frac{2-a-b}{ab-1}
$$

which is non null inside any of the four quadrants.

NOTE

The quadrant verification suffices because $x = 0$ and $y = 0$ are orbits.

Comment: So what? Limit cycle can encircle a focus or a node, not only a center equilibrium.

Comment: In this case, which is not the one focused into the exercise, it should be used the Poincaré–Bendixson theorem.